# combine asset data values ​from two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two asset-related data tables with the same table structure, namely the KIB B table and the KIB BR table
The KIB B table contains asset data (the initial price of the asset and there is only one asset with one id)
The KIB BR table contains asset data (asset prices based on conditions and accommodates more than one of the same id)

I want to retrieve the asset value from the kib br table and search for the data based on the asset id
when the same asset data is found it will automatically retrieve the value from the kib br table
but in the br kib there are several asset conditions with codes 1,2,3,5,6
if asset data is found with the same id then the asset price value in the kib b table will be calculated with the asset values ​​in the kib br table to get the net asset value
asset value kib b - condition 3 kib br(if any) - condition 5 kib br(if any)- condition 6kib br(if any) + condition 2kib br(if any) + condition 1 kib br(if any) = value shown in new column kib b

is the formula suitable for this case? Thank You

solve the case with a suitable excel formula to get the expected value

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output as well as your effort (current formula you tried).

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be better way to do so with Power Query in Excel.
You can easily find tutorials on YouTube or on the Web.
Here just one article with video tutorial from many like this:
[Merge tables with Power Query](https://www.excelcampus.com/powerquery/power-query-combine-tables/)